# How to Disable Dropdown Option based on selection of other dropdown?

Tags: angular

I need to disable selected value from other dropdown based on selected value in from the current dropdown
Below I mentioned my case.

I have dynamic dropdown so every dropdown belongs to the same headerList array.

There are no. of dropdowns.

For example:

I have total of 10 Dropdowns. if user select Email from the First dropdown then all other dropdowns should disable this Email option and if the user changes selected value from Email to Phone number then Email should be enabled for all dropdowns and phone number should be disabled for all.

**app.component.ts**

```
public headerList :string[]=['First Name','Last Name','Company Name','Email','Phone Number','Lead Source','Details','Address 1','Address 2','City','State','Country','Zip','Tags','Assign To'];
public disabledDropdownItems : string[]=[];

onDropdownChange(event,index){
        
        if(event.target.value != ""){
                this.disabledDropdownItems.push(event.target.value);
                this.selectedDropdownColumns.push(index+';'+event.target.value);
        }
        else{
            
            let deselectItem =  this.selectedDropdownColumns.filter(item => item.includes(index+";"));
            
            if(deselectItem != undefined && deselectItem.length > 0 ){
                this.disabledDropdownItems.splice(this.disabledDropdownItems.indexOf(deselectItem[0],1));
                this.selectedDropdownColumns = this.selectedDropdownColumns.filter( selectedItem => selectedItem != deselectItem[0]);   
            }
            
        }
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let header of manageLeadDataDto.header;let i = index"><br>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input class="h-w-15" id="{{i}}" type="checkbox" (click)="onSelectDeselectCheckBox($event,i);"
                                        title="Select {{header}}">
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">{{header}}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <select  class="selectpicker" (change)="onDropdownChange($event,i);">
                <option value="" [selected]="true">Please select value</option>
                <option *ngFor="let header of headerList" value="{{header}}" [disabled]="disabledDropdownItems.includes(header)">{{header}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Above is my code but it not disabling dropdown values

Comment: Are you aware, that you have two loops that defined header from two different lists. This looks very strange. If you have nested list normaly the inner list uses some value from the outer list. Probably your outer list should not be let header but let headerList?

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty simple, all we have to do is to keep that index and selected value in a variable, here

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let header of [1,2,3,4,5];let i = index"><br>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input class="h-w-15" id="{{i}}" type="checkbox" (click)="onSelectDeselectCheckBox($event,i);"
                                        title="Select {{header}}">
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">{{header}}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <select  class="selectpicker" (change)="onDropdownChange($event,i);">
                <option value="" [selected]="true">Please select value</option>
                <option *ngFor="let header of headerList; let j = index"
                value="{{header}}"
                [disabled] = 'header===disabledItem &&  (selectIndex && selectIndex != i+1)'
                >{{header}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in your ts

```
 disabledItem ='';
  selectIndex = 0;
public headerList :string[]=['First Name','Last Name','Company Name','Email','Phone Number','Lead Source','Details','Address 1','Address 2','City','State','Country','Zip','Tags','Assign To'];


onDropdownChange(event , i){
this.selectIndex = i+1;
this.disabledItem = event.target.value;
console.log(event.target.value , i)


}
```

refer this working demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-giemqz?file=src/app/app.component.html